# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long' error when submitting form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this in thecontroller:

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/update",
            params = {"new_profile_image"},
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateUserProfileImage(
            @RequestParam(value = "new_profile_image") CommonsMultipartFile newProfileImage,
            ModelMap model) {

        System.out.println("controller executed!");

        if(newProfileImage != null && !newProfileImage.isEmpty()) {
            updateService.updateUserProfileImage(newProfileImage.getBytes());
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/users/my_profile");
    }
```

And in the jsp file:

```
<form action="<c:url value='/users/update?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}' />" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="new_profile_image" type="file" id="new_profile_image">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
```

when I submit an image I am getting

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Feb 08 19:08:10 CST 2020 There was an unexpected error (type=Bad
>   Request, status=400). Failed to convert value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "update"

The string `"controller executed!"` never shows up in the console. I changed `value = "/update"` by `value = "/updateImage"` in the RequestMapping annotation and `action="<c:url value='/users/update?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}' />"` by `action="<c:url value='/users/updateImage?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}' />"` and the error message chaged to `nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "updateImage"`

I have no idea what is wrong and in the eclipse's console no exception is shown.

Edited:
I forgot to say that the controller has `RequestMapping("/users")` at class level.

Now I changed in the controller `value = "/update"` by `value = "/updateImage"`, but i left `action="<c:url value='/users/update?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}' />"` in the jsp page, and the error still is:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sat Feb 08 19:08:10 CST 2020 There was an unexpected error (type=Bad
>   Request, status=400). Failed to convert value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "update"

I guess the request is not even reaching the controller.

Comment: @R.G do you mean jsp is trying to convert the string `'/users/update?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}'` to Long?

Comment: No . My question was wrong . I had a misunderstanding regarding the code

Comment: Usually `RequestParam` is used with `GET` requests, maybe that is why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem by erasing the `params` attribute from `@RequestMapping`. So, the controller endded up as:

```
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/updateImage",
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateUserProfileImage(
            @RequestParam(value = "new_profile_image", required = true) CommonsMultipartFile newProfileImage,
            ModelMap model) {

        System.out.println("controller executed!");

        if(newProfileImage != null && !newProfileImage.isEmpty()) {
            updateService.updateUserProfileImage(newProfileImage.getBytes());
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/users/my_profile");
    }
```

I have used `params` attribute with post request in other methods and it works, I guess the problem here has to do with the request being a multi-part request. But I do not really know what the actual proble is.